# Change Opacity of an HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to create an overlay which is displayed when a graphic on an HTML canvas element is clicked. My current problem is changing the CSS opacity of the overlay element.

To do this I am using the two CSS classes below:

```
.Overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: BLUE;
}
.Overlay-Open {
  opacity: 1;
  background: RED;
}
```

and changing the class by using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("Node-Data").setAttribute("class","Overlay-Open");
```

I am slowly going insane, because I can not understand why the background colour changes, but not the opacity. Can someone lend me some of their wizardly knowledge to debug this issue? I will provide more code if needed.

**UPDATE**

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/c6bdmo94/) *click a node

Replaced

```
document.getElementById("Node-Data").setAttribute("class","Overlay-Open");
```

with

```
document.getElementById("Node-Data").classList.add('Overlay-Open');
document.getElementById("Node-Data").classList.remove('Overlay');
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce — http://jsbin.com/cuqiyidudu/1/ — try providing a test case that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#run) please..

Comment: While asking questions try always to provide the minimal code example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an appropriate way to manipulate `class` elements in JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('Node-Data');
el.classList.add('Overlay-Open');
el.classList.remove('Overlay');
```

Is working OK for me, take a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/ZYByNK), the opacity and the background color change after 2 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for that bit of code, I have updated my script.

Comment: @bostelb I have take a look at your pen, the problem is that the aside whit id 'Node-Overlay' (which contains the 'Node-Data') has also the class Overlay. Inspect it with dev tools and you will find it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so blind now, the issue was that I added the class to Node-Data and not Node-Overlay (typo). I was going insane re-writing just about everything and searching the internet for similar issues. Spent almost an hour now, and yet the issue was so simple!